# Windows boot manager does not recognizes dual OS

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I have Hp pavilion series laptop, I recently tried to install windows 10 fall creators update on my OS partition again by formating the partition first. But after successful installation, windows boot manager does not recognizes my debian on another partition, maybe it has lost grub2. I dont know how to solve this problem. If any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but the issue is that grub was overwritten with the Windows boot loader. Here are some links that should help you with repairing Grub: 
https://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

When I duel booted my computer, I found that the simplest way is to reinstall Ubuntu which will return the Grub menu.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not recognize non windows OSs. you need to use grub (or another linux friendly bootmanager) as your boot manager. The Creators update is known for deleting linux partitions, I'm not sure if a fresh install has the same issue.

First step:
go into your EFI firmware and see if you can select OS to boot.

If your firmware only allows device boot, then you need to make grub the default boot manager following these directions: https://askubuntu.com/a/960987/694267

If your EFI System Partition does not have /efi/debian/grubx64.efi, then you need to reinstall grub. These directions can be used to boot into your current install from a grub command prompt: https://askubuntu.com/a/931327/694267